# Fingerings for Chromatic Third Scales on the Piano

Tags: piano, fingering, chromatic

Can someone enumerate the main fingerings for major (... → C-E → C♯-F → …) and minor (... → C-E♭ → C♯-E → …) chromatic third scales? I've heard that Czerny, Moszkowski, Chopin and Godowski each had unique fingerings of situational suitability. I'd also like to know which fingerings Rafael Joseffy used since I prefer his exercises.

Comment: Since everyone's hands and fingers are subtly different in their length and mobility, any fingering guide will be at best just a suggestion that someone feels is best - for them. Bearing that in mind, a player's best option is to slowly work out what fingering works best for *them*.

Comment: I've usually seen an alternating 1-3, 2-4 pattern, but occasionally I've come across some 1-4, 2-5 alternating pattern. As Tim says, it depends on your hands, and I've even altered fingering from what was written on chromatic third passages recently.

Comment: I understand and usually alter provided fingerings but it is nice not to have to start from scratch for the building block of a scale. There are so many possible fingerings, most to be avoided especially at high velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the fingerings that Rafael Joseffy uses for minor thirds. His fingering for major thirds does not seem to be publicly known.

Vladimir de Pachmann, Moritz Moszkowski, Ferruccio Busoni, and Alberto Jonas also have used the following fingering.

First line of numbers is RH and second line is LH:

31 42 51 32 42 31 42 31 42 51 32 42 31(2) 41 32 51 42 31 42 32 41 32 51 42 31

24 23 14 23 15 24 13 24 23 14 32 15 24    15 23 24 12 24 13 24 15 23 24 13 24

*Note, the first notes are C and Eb*